# Typescript Singleton Undefined Attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, singleton

I'm trying to create a singleton that has a single amqp connection and when createChannel method is called, it must return a new channel from the same connection:

```js
export interface IBroker {
  createChannel(): Promise<IChannel>;
}

export default class Broker implements IBroker {
  private static instance: Broker;

  private conn: IConnection | undefined;

  private constructor(public config: IRabbitMQConfig = new RabbitMQConfig()) {}

  /**
   * singleton
   */
  public static getInstance(): Broker {
    if (!this.instance) {
      this.instance = new Broker();
    }
    return this.instance;
  }

  /**
   * initiates configuration on infra service
   */
  async createChannel(): Promise<IChannel> {
    try {
      if (!this.conn) {
        this.conn = await this.config.init();
        await this.createExchanges();
        await this.createQueues();
        await this.createBinds();
        logger.info('Broker started successfully');
      }
      if (!this.conn) {
        throw new InternalError('Error starting broker. Missing connection!');
      }
      return await this.conn.createChannel();
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error('Error trying to start broker', err);
      throw new InternalError('Error trying to start broker', 500);
    }
  }

// code...
```

the call config.init() returns the amqp connection.

when  I test the class like below, every time I call createChannel it creates a new connection!

```js
    const a = Broker.getInstance();
    const b = Broker.getInstance();
    console.log(a === b); // return true
    a.createChannel(); // create a new connection
    b.createChannel(); // creates another connection
```

this.conn of Broker class is always undefined when createChannel is called!

Comment: How are you determining that it makes a new connection? Does the first `if (!this.conn)` branch always evaluate to `true`?

Comment: I'v logged the this.conn, every time i call createChannel method of Broker, it is undefinde! and the message broker started sucessfully always shows too.

Comment: Shouldn't you be awaiting the `createChannel` calls? By the time you call `b.createChannel` it's likely the `async` operation to initialize it hasn't finished yet.

Comment: off course that is the problem.. I'm sorry borring you with this stupid error... thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that the two synchronous calls to `createChannel` mean that the first one hasn't initialized the connection by the time the second is called, which leads to 2 connections being created.

If you want to make your `createChannel` "thread-safe" in terms of creating the connection, you could do something like this (untested):

```
interface IConnection {
    connect: () => void
}

const initConnection = () : Promise<IConnection> => {
    return Promise.resolve({
        connect: () => {}
    });
};

class Broker {
    private connection : IConnection | undefined;
    private pendingConnection : Promise<IConnection> | undefined;

    async createChannel() : Promise<IConnection> {
        if (this.connection) {
            return this.connection;
        }

        if (this.pendingConnection) {
            return this.pendingConnection;
        }

        this.pendingConnection = initConnection();
        const conn = await this.pendingConnection;
        // Do other setup stuff
        this.connection = conn;
        this.pendingConnection = undefined;
        return conn;
    }
}
```